# fitting on X_train and y_train

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

For somebody super beginner how can one remember what to pass into model.fit?
I have to keep on looking up that we are supposed to pass X_train, y_train.
But I guess I don't fully understand why we don't pass in something else such as:
X_train, y_test.

Thank you!
Josh

Answer (score 2):

X are your features and y are your associated labels. Your model may only see the test data in the evaluation step.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/train-test-split-for-evaluating-machine-learning-algorithms/

Answer (score 0):

Passing X_train and y_test will result in a data mismatch: once you have splitted your data in training and test set (here's [why](https://blog.roboflow.com/train-test-split/) you do it and [some ways](https://machinelearningmastery.com/train-test-split-for-evaluating-machine-learning-algorithms/) to do that), you will have the output/label of your X_train in your y_train, and that goes the same for your test set.

Answer (score 0):

We pass train data(X_train, y_train) during fit so that our model will find the parameters that build the relationship between the independent and dependent variables.

To test if we have built the correct relationship we will evaluate unseen data ( test data). That is when we use .prdeict on X_test and find the values of y_test_predict.